# 500 Error When Attempting to Echo Form data in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am getting an error page from the server when trying to view my test.php page. Everything on the page loads fine if I remove the php tags. 
I am getting an "http error 500" with the following code:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>   
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<Title>Test</Title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/default.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "<form>
<input type="hidden" name="uid" value="Anonymous">
<input type="hidden" name="date" value='".date()."'>
<textarea name="Message"></textarea><br>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Comment</button>
</form>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to escape " character in string while using php

Comment: Or use single quotes at the appropriate places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:-

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>   
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<Title>Test</Title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/default.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "<form>
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"uid\" value=\"Anonymous\">
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"date\" value='".date()."'>
<textarea name=\"Message\"></textarea><br>
<button type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\">Comment</button>
</form>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Either use \" to escape " character in the string or enclose the whole string in ' quotes to escape " or vice versa.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was a newbie error but I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Or even strip out most of the echo/print

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>   
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<Title>Test</Title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/default.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="uid" value="Anonymous">
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php print(date()); ?>">
<textarea name="Message"></textarea><br>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Comment</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This would be my preferred choice given the situation. Why stuff a bunch of needless html into an echo in the first place if the rest of the page around it is not? ;)

Answer (score 1):

```

```
<?php
echo '<form>
<input type="hidden" name="uid" value="Anonymous">
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="'.date().'">
<textarea name="Message"></textarea><br>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Comment</button>
</form>';
?>
```

```
this should work.

Comment: If you gotta stuff that much in an echo, might as well make it easier than dealing with a glob of backslashes! Using the single quote helps greatly there.